# Matlab: How do I put another function within a function?

Tags: matlab

I have a function in Matlab that produces three specific results. I want to use these results as input arguments to a following function to calculate the end result.

How do I go about combining the two functions?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if I understand your question. As far as I understand you have a function1 that gives three output arguments that you want to use as inputs to a function2. In that case you could either just let the functions be separate and use them as

```
[a,b,c] = function1();
endResult = function2(a,b,c);
```

Or you could nest them by putting function1 within function2. You would do that by just appending function1 to the function2 file. In shell:

```
cat function2.m function1.m > function2.m
```

or just use an editor. You will have to edit the new function anyway, e.g. by adding the two Matlab code lines above just before defining function1.m.

Is that any help?